`assert_never()` fails on match-casing a custom class with an enum field
Here is the code to reproduce:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import StrEnum, auto
from typing import assert_never

class RGBColor(StrEnum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
    GREEN = auto()

@dataclass
class FooData:
    number: int
    color: RGBColor

def fn() -> FooData:
    return FooData(10, RGBColor.RED)

obj = fn()
match obj:
    case FooData(color=RGBColor.RED):
        print("case 1")
    case FooData(color=RGBColor.BLUE):
        print("case 2")
    case FooData(color=RGBColor.GREEN):
        print("case 3")
    case _ as never:
        assert_never(never)

Mypy error:
error: Argument 1 to "assert_never" has incompatible type "FooData"; expected "Never"  [arg-type]

Pyright error:
Argument of type "FooData" cannot be assigned to parameter "__arg" of type "Never" in function "assert_never"
  Type "FooData" cannot be assigned to type "Never"PylancereportArgumentType

Is it something that I'm missing here? I think I covered all cases in the pattern-matching. obj is of a FooData type because it is returned from the fn() function and its .color attribute can be any of the RGBColor's member.

additional information:
Type checking passes if I only used the bare enum (without being an attribute of an object):
from enum import StrEnum, auto
from typing import assert_never

class RGBColor(StrEnum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
    GREEN = auto()

def fn() -> RGBColor:
    return RGBColor.RED

obj = fn()
match obj:
    case RGBColor.RED:
        print("case 1")
    case RGBColor.BLUE:
        print("case 2")
    case RGBColor.GREEN:
        print("case 3")
    case _ as never:
        assert_never(never)


The fact that you can't create new instances of RGBColor (if that is, indeed, a fact) isn't something that a type checker can be expected to know. enum is a library, not a language feature.

@chepner Thanks. apparently type checkers are aware of enums, but when they become a member of class they have no idea. I've updated the question to show that

@chepner seems like there is no chance with custom objects

That's somewhat surprising. I can imagine it would take some additional logic to handle FooData(color=RGBColor.Red), but not that much more than what's needed to handle case RGBColor.RED in the first place.
